# Removing spaces: Unicode properties - character classes

Tags: regex, perl

Do these two substitutions always yield the same results?

```
$data =~ s/\p{Space}//g;

$data =~ s/[\h\v]//g;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
$ diff -U0 \
      <( unichars -au '\p{Space}' ) \
      <( unichars -au '[\h\v]'    ) \
   && echo No differences
No differences
```

Contrast with

```
$ diff -U0 \
      <( unichars -au '\p{Space}' ) \
      <( unichars -au '\s'        ) \
   && echo No differences
--- /dev/fd/63  2012-07-20 11:28:33.356934588 -0400
+++ /dev/fd/62  2012-07-20 11:28:33.356934588 -0400
@@ -3 +2,0 @@
- ---- U+0000B LINE TABULATION
```

`\s` might start including U+000B soon, though.

`unichars` is installed by [Unicode::Tussle](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3a%3aTussle).

---

Note: Without `/u` or `use 5.012;`, `\s` sometimes doesn't match NBSP.

---

I just found a bug in Perl (5.16.0). Reporting it immediately.

```
$ perl -le'print "\xA0" =~ /\p{Space}/ ?1:0'
1

$ perl -le'print "\xA0" =~ /\s/ ?1:0'
0

$ perl -le'print "\xA0" =~ /\s/u ?1:0'
1
                                         __
$ perl -le'print "\xA0" =~ /\h/ ?1:0'      \
1                                           \
                                             > huh??
$ perl -le'print "\xA0" =~ /[\h]/ ?1:0'     /
0                                        __/

$ perl -le'print "\xA0" =~ /[\h]/u ?1:0'
1
```

So that means, no, `\p{Space}` and `[\h\v]` are only equivalent if `/u` or `use 5.012;` is used.

[Ticket #114220](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=114220)

Status:

- `/\h/` is equivalent to `/[\h]/` in 5.10, 5.12, 5.14 and 5.18
- `/\h/` is not equivalent to `/[\h]/` in 5.16.0
- Don't know about 5.16.1

Comment: @tchrist, This post is relevant to your interests.

Comment: I’ve been watching the p5p blotter on this.